# How to programmatically execute these three steps?

Tags: installation, setup-project, vsix, vdproj

I need programmatically execute these steps for my project VSIX.

1. Right click Application Folder -> Add -> project output
2. Select your respective project's solution "primary output from yours.."
3. Right click setup project in solution explorer and BUILD it.

Comment: There is a Visual Studio Automation Object Model, EnvDTE and so on. I'd look there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing that [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) excells at, although there's probably a command-line interface which would provide a cleaner way to automate that task.